# How do I fix write:errno104 when executing "openssl s_client -connect mydomain:993"?

Tags: linux, archlinux, postfix-mta, dovecot

I am creating my own mail server using this guide. http://aurellem.org/free/html/email.html

When I run **sudo journalctl | grep dovecot | less** I get:

```
     imap-login: Error: Failed to initialize SSL server context: 
    Couldn't parse DH parameters: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio
enter code here:no start line:
     Expecting: DH PARAMETERS: user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<WzFXoLNmztUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" realated and is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/), [**Server Fault**](http://serverfault.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your ssl_dh configuration setting is missing, or the file it points to is missing or damaged.